# How to open a GUI with sudo permissions without theme changes in sudo and from a .desktop file

Tags: command-line, sudo, gui, .desktop

## TL, DR: I want to be able to launch a GUI application with root priviliges via double clicking a .desktop file, and by preserving the good(relative to the sudo way) looking non-sudo way theme.

---

I have looked related questions/answers in here, however, I cannot say that I understand the situation and found a solution. Either they were not either well structured and explatory, or I just did not get them. OR most of them were mentioning `gksu`, however, as far as I understood, `gksu` has been removed from the repositories. I cannot install it.

Screenshot can be found as attached at the end of the question.

I am aware it will be a messy question, please pardon me.

---

Now, I have Quartus program installed on my computer, and I can run it via(LEFT SIDE OF THE SCREENSHOT):

```
/home/muyustan/altera/13.1/quartus/bin/quartus --64bit
```

I also had created a `.desktop` file as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=0.9.4
Name=Quartus II 13.1 (64-bit) Web Edition
Comment=Quartus II 13.1 (64-bit)
Icon=/home/muyustan/altera/13.1/quartus/adm/quartusii.png
Exec=/home/muyustan/altera/13.1/quartus/bin/quartus --64bit
Terminal=false
Path=/home/muyustan/altera/13.1
```

So far so good, I can run it via desktop entry, no terminal window pops up and halts there(annoying enough). Everything is fine.

However, I figured out that in a part of the Quartus app, it has to open(call) another program(Modelsim) and save some files to some places etc. The problem is, if I don't launch the app with a `sudo` in front of it(RIGHT SIDE OF THE SCREENSHOT), I get some errors stating `permission denied` and things just don't get working.

So, I can solve this by changing my launching habbit,

```
from -- double click on the desktop entry

to -- Ctrl+Alt+T -> sudo [executablePath] -> enter password
```

Now, clearly I won't want this because of two main reasons.

1. It takes longer time.
2. That terminal stays there as long as the application is open.

And right at this point a 3rd(bonus) reason pops up, as you may or may not have noticed from the screenshots, launching with `sudo` makes the GUI theme looking like, well, Windows XP style... I haven't chosen/changed any theme when I first installed Quartus or so, by the way.

**So, I hope I made my point clear.**

Thanks in advance.

[image]

---

#### Updates to the question

After someone's request in the comments, see the error I am getting in the called(launched from inside of Quartus) application, Modelsim:

```
do temp1_run_msim_rtl_verilog.do 
# if {[file exists rtl_work]} {
#   vdel -lib rtl_work -all
# }
# ** Error: (vdel-19) Failed to access library 'rtl_work' at "/home/muyustan/altera/13.1/temp1/simulation/qsim/rtl_work".
# Permission denied. (errno = EACCES)
# ** Error: /home/muyustan/altera/13.1/modelsim_ase/linux/vdel failed.
# Error in macro ./temp1_run_msim_rtl_verilog.do line 4
# /home/muyustan/altera/13.1/modelsim_ase/linux/vdel failed.
#     while executing
# "vdel -lib rtl_work -all"
#     invoked from within
# "if {[file exists rtl_work]} {
#   vdel -lib rtl_work -all
# }"
```

Comment: Could you add the error messages you get? probably worth fixing them then running such  GUI app with a root power.

Comment: @user.dz see my update please

Comment: I take it this is Windows software you are running in WINE or a VM? Not sure why it needs root access.

Comment: @Syd I did not say anything about wine or VM :confused:

Comment: From what I can find (and I might be wrong) Quartus is a windows only program.

Comment: @Syd, it is Linux version, as you can see, I used it before. and could be downloaded from  https://fpgasoftware.intel.com/?edition=lite

Comment: OK. Did not find that before. Still, why does it need root permissions to run at all?

Comment: @Syd it does not require root permissions only to run, it runs without sudo, however at some point, It calls n external program(modelsim) to simulate the design. At that point, the modelsim pops up(opens) however, gives an error(I attached at the end of my question) in its terminal.

Comment: Probably installed it using `sudo` into home folder. @muyustan could you add output of `find /home/muyustan/altera -type d -exec stat -c '%A %G %U %n' {} \;`

Comment: @user.dz it outputted like thousands of lines, all of them are directories I guess(all lines start with `d`), are you sure you want that? If so, I will do a `>>` into a file and upload it to somewhere and will provide you the link.

Comment: @muyustan, you can post few lines if that have same permission and owner, just check

Comment: @user.dz it looks like most of them(almost all, but there are 20.5 k lines) has `drwxr-xr-x`. please find the file here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=178oE4CZj_xyNFPwmG390YqbcChZ3A4LG

Comment: @muyustan you a have ownership issue, when you run, even once before as root, it created a temporary folder which can't be accessed when you run with normal privileges. Try fix it using: `sudo chown -R muyustan:muyustan /home/muyustan/altera` which change child folders and files in that altera folder ownership to your user and group. Try again runnning Quartus  without `sudo`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106754/discussion-between-user-dz-and-muyustan).

Comment: @user.dz I don't know will it notify you or not, I wrote you from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User got this error message:

> ```
> # ** Error: (vdel-19) Failed to access library 'rtl_work' at "/home/muyustan/altera/13.1/temp1/simulation/qsim/rtl_work".
> # Permission denied. (errno = EACCES)
> ```

From the use of `sudo`, I expected some folders/files were created with root privileges level.

1. We generated listing for whole tree in "altera" folder to verify ownership and permissions. Using:

   ```
   find /home/muyustan/altera -type d -exec stat -c '%A %G %U %n' {} \; > log.txt
   ```
2. Look for that folder `temp1` or the user/group `root`, as you could see there are folders owned by root

   ```
   drwxrwxr-x muyustan muyustan /home/muyustan/altera/13.1/temp1/simulation/qsim/work/up_counter
   drwxrwxr-x muyustan muyustan /home/muyustan/altera/13.1/temp1/simulation/qsim/work/prime_detector_4bits_vlg_check_tst
   drwxr-xr-x root root /home/muyustan/altera/13.1/temp1/simulation/qsim/rtl_work
   drwxr-xr-x root root /home/muyustan/altera/13.1/temp1/simulation/qsim/rtl_work/_temp
   drwxr-xr-x root root /home/muyustan/altera/13.1/temp1/simulation/qsim/rtl_work/up_counter_tb
   drwxr-xr-x root root /home/muyustan/altera/13.1/temp1/simulation/qsim/rtl_work/up_counter
   drwxrwxr-x muyustan muyustan /home/muyustan/altera/13.1/temp1/simulation/modelsim
   drwxr-xr-x root root /home/muyustan/altera/13.1/temp1/simulation/modelsim/gate_work
   drwxr-xr-x root root /home/muyustan/altera/13.1/temp1/simulation/modelsim/gate_work/prime_detector_4bits
   drwxr-xr-x root root /home/muyustan/altera/13.1/temp1/simulation/modelsim/gate_work/_temp
   drwxr-xr-x root root /home/muyustan/altera/13.1/temp1/simulation/modelsim/rtl_work
   drwxr-xr-x root root /home/muyustan/altera/13.1/temp1/simulation/modelsim/rtl_work/_temp
   drwxr-xr-x root root /home/muyustan/altera/13.1/temp1/simulation/modelsim/rtl_work/up_counter
   drwxrwxr-x muyustan muyustan /home/muyustan/altera/13.1/temp1/db
   drwxrwxr-x muyustan muyustan /home/muyustan/altera/13.1/temp1/incremental_db
   ```
3. Change the ownership of that altera folder and all child folders and files in it to your user and group.

   ```
   sudo chown -R muyustan:muyustan /home/muyustan/altera
   ```

Try again running Quartus without `sudo`

Comment: yes! exact shot to the point

Comment: I have sent you some message on chat, it shows you left the room, I don't know if it is permanent or not, so I am typing here to notify you